# Comparing row values with an integer

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have 2 columns and the rows look like this...

```
1   2
2   3
6   10
11  2
```

I have these 2 formulas and the first returns True and the second False.

```
=ROW(A1:B4)<=2

=ROW(A1:B4)>=2
```

I do not understand the logic behind this. I think both should either return True or False.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but LibreOffice help-page says about this: "If the ROW function with a range reference is not used in an array formula, only the row number of the first range cell will be returned."

Therefore `=ROW(A1:B4)` always returns `1` (which is row number of A1 cell).

https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=4.2/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions&Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=4.2#ROW

Comment: I am trying to understand the formula =SUMPRODUCT(A1:B4*(ROW(A1:B4)>=D1)*(ROW(A1:B4)<=D2)) that I found here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868052/sum-using-row-range-specified-on-other-cells-in-libreoffice-calc

Comment: Ah, that’s what you’re asking! Then try entering each of your formulas as an [**array formula**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html) (finish typing Сtrl+Shift+Enter) and you will see that the first one gives the result `TRUE|TRUE|FALSE|FALSE`, and the second one `FALSE|TRUE|TRUE|TRUE`.

Comment: Since [**SUMPRODUCT()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3163286) knows that it works with arrays, then when ROW() is compared with a constant inside this function, then Ctrl+Shift+Enter is not required